# There is no Authorization Button on Swagger

Tags: java, spring, swagger

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .securityContexts(Arrays.asList(securityContext()))
                .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(apiKey()))
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build().apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title(title)
                .description(description)
                .version(version)
                .build();
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder()
                .securityReferences(defaultAuth())
                .build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
        return Arrays.asList(new SecurityReference("Authorization", authorizationScopes));
    }

    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("Authorization", "Authorization", "header");
    }
}
```

I can find the Authorization Button on localhost's Swagger UI, but on deployed site, I can't find it. I tried deploying on several times but it always failed.